# Unwanted delay between starting each BackgroundWorker array element

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, backgroundworker

I want to create an array of BackgroundWorkers which work alongside each other to take advantage of multicore processors. Let's say I want eight of them working simultaneously. I also want a separate Timer thread to report in the GUI on some data which each of the threads has been processing.

My problem is this. It takes around 3-4 seconds for each worker to start work. So the first worker element in the array starts straight away. The second starts a few seconds after. The third starts a few seconds after that etc. etc.

I want them all to start straight away. How can I fix this?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    BackgroundWorker[] bw;
    int threads = 8;
    data[] d;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        d = new data[threads];
        for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++) d[i] = new data(i);

        bw = new BackgroundWorker[threads];
        for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++)
        {
            bw[i] = new BackgroundWorker();
            bw[i].DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(Work);
        }
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++) bw[i].RunWorkerAsync(d[i]);
    }

    private void Work(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        data o = (data)e.Argument;
        while (true) o.count += o.id;
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        long total = 0;
        for (int n = 0; n < threads; n++) {
            sb.Append(d[n].id + ": " + d[n].count + "\n");
            total+=d[n].count;
        }
        sb.Append("TOTAL: "+total);
        richTextBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
    }



}

public class data {
    public int id;
    public long count;
    public data(int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.count = 0;
    }
}
```

-------------------------------EDIT: Found out later than the 3-4 second delay only applies beyond the maximum number of logical cores you have. So if you have 20 cores, and set 20 threads that's fine. However, if you have 4 cores, and set 20 threads, there will a delay between creating each of the 16 threads beyond the first 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want them all to start straight away.

Then Backgroundworkers are not the right tool. And maybe even Windows is not the right OS.

Backgroundworkers run on the ThreadPool, the guideline is to use that only for short (< 500ms) tasks. The Threadpool creates new threads at 2/second (roughly).

The short solution is to increase ThreadPool.Minthreads (look up the actual name/method) but that's still a whacky solution.

You did not provide enough (real) information for a better advice.

Comment: Wow, your `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads` idea works - thanks! My concern is that with a quad-core processor and an embarassingly-parallel problem, 4 cores should be almost 4x as quick as 1 core. What would usually be a 10-second problem with a single core should be about 3 seconds with a quad core (very roughly). However, if each thread takes 3 seconds to start, then the problem could take about 6-7 seconds instead. In other words, I want all the cores to start work ASAP and not hang around. If they're there, then they should be ready and willing to be used.

Comment: Oh just to add, if BackgroundWorkers are meant for <500ms tasks (though it's hard to see why as they seem fast otherwise), then would Threads be more appropriate for my purposes? Tasks could run into minutes or even tens of minutes for what I'm doing.

Comment: When they run into minutes, a 0.5 second starting delay shouldn't matter much. But it is better to either use Tasks (with the LongRunning option) or to create bare threads for this.

Comment: It's 3s starting delay, not 0.5s btw (and that would multiply with each successive core). So if hypothetically, I go the BackgroundWorker route, would I expect to see a decrease in performance, memory usage, or some other problem?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, that the line `while (true) o.count += o.id;` consumes so much CPU that other operations may be blocked.

Try to add `Thread.Sleep(100);` before `o.count += o.id;` or reduce the number of threads (8 threads + GUI thread => 9 Threads just for your application).

Comment: Thanks. Now I get about 0.5s between each new worker. Not ideal and in any case, I don't want to slow the main loop down as my program (which isn't this short code sample in the main Q) requires performance. I tried reducing the number of threads to 5 to no avail.